# How can I get the user calling a web service even though the ws is being impersonated?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, impersonation

I have an application which is basically a web service, this connects to a sql db with specific user credentials in the impersonate tag in the web config.

**What I want to know is if it is possible to get the user name who is calling this web service.**

My web config looks like this:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="db_user" password="db_pass" />
```

Im making an http request using the following credentials:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("request_user", "request_pass");
```

And inside the webmethod of the webservice Im trying the following lines of code to get the request user but they all return the same user which is the impersonating user -(

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name //returns db_user
System.Environment.UserName //returns db_user
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name //returns db_user
```

Am I being clear? hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the username into the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to create a new application pool in the IIS and make it run as the user required to access the database, then just impersonate the web service.